# Simplify fraction $4x/(x-1)$ to $ 4+(4/(x-1))$

Tags: fractions

I have put the fraction into Symbolab which gives some step-by-step explanation on why this os correct, but I am unable to grasp how this is possible.

Comment: I suggest that you transcribe the step-by-step explanation you have, and then explain how much you understand and where you get stuck or confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding and $+4$ and $-4$ to the numerator, if $x\in \Bbb R \setminus \{1\}$, you have:

$$\frac{4x}{x-1}=\frac{(4x-4)+4}{x-1}=\frac{4x-4}{x-1}+\frac4{x-1}=4\frac{x-1}{x-1}+\frac4{x-1}=4+\frac4{x-1}$$

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I am looking for. Totally forgot you could add and substract like that.

Comment: @GertjanBrouwer There's no problem with me. In fact, it is a sincere pleasure. Do you know how much I forget? Many many. :-)

Comment: Good to hear I am not the only one forgetting things!

Comment: @GertjanBrouwer I always put humility and sincerity first, but this bothers a lot of people.

Comment: Well I really do appreciate it, thanks again